# Setting the colorbar after plotting data inside a loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to plot some finite element results using `tricontourf` in `matplotlib`. To do so, a `for` loop needs to be created that accounts for the data at the nodes of each element (something like the `fill` command in MATLAB). This works nicely, but the problem lies in the display of the `colorbar`. It only shows the values of the last element (after the loop finishes) and it does not include the values of the whole domain.

Therefore, is there a way to 'accumulate' the data of the `tricontourf` so that the colorbar includes the values of the whole domain, or maybe a way to manipulate the `colorbar` to do so? I tried to append the data using `contour_sets.append()` and then use this as input to `colorbar`, but it does not work.

The code looks like this:

```
# nodes and coordinates 
IEN  = np.array([[1,2,5,6],[2,3,4,5],[5,4,9,8],[6,5,8,7]])   # nodes vs elements
xx   = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])            # x coordinates
yy   = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])            # y coordinates
zz   = np.array([50, 40, 30, 45, 20, 30, 30, 15, 10])   # magnitude
nen,nfe = np.shape(IEN)     # nodes per element, number of elements

#contour_sets = []
fig = plt.figure(1)
for e in range(nfe):
   idx = np.squeeze(IEN[:,e]-1)   # take the element nodes
   x   = xx[idx]                  # x coordinates of element e
   y   = yy[idx]                  # y coordinates of element e
   z   = zz[idx]                  # magnitude values of element e

   # additional node in the middle to be able to use tricontourf
   x5  = np.mean(x)               # x coordinate 
   y5  = np.mean(y)               # y coordinate 
   z5  = np.mean(z)               # magnitude value

   # set up the triangle nodes (rectangular element as two triangles)
   triangles = np.array([ [ 2, 4, 1 ], 
                          [ 2, 3, 4 ], ]) -1      

   # insert the additional middle node to the coordinates
   xt = np.insert(x,nen,[x5]).squeeze()       
   yt = np.insert(y,nen,[y5]).squeeze()      
   zt = np.insert(z,nen,[z5]).squeeze()  

   # plot the data           
   fil = plt.tricontourf(xt, yt, triangles, zt, norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=zz.max(), vmin=zz.min()), cmap=cm.pink) 
   #contour_sets.append(fil)

# organize the plot       
cb = plt.colorbar(fil, shrink=0.95, aspect=15, pad = 0.05)
cb.ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')                         
cb.update_ticks()
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,3.1,0.5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(1,3.1,0.5))
plt.xlim(1, 3)
plt.ylim(1, 3)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.tight_layout()
```

which gives this Figure (edited for clarification purposes):
[The `colorbar` only shows the values of `zz` asociated to the element 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4HRK.jpg)

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi @AllanLRH, it was already simplified, this code only shows 4 rectangular elements. I included some comments though.

Comment: Since each plot has its own `norm`, it makes little sense to draw one colorbar for all plots, because they do not have the same colors associated to the same values (e.g. a value of x may be pink in one plot, but white in another). There it would be beneficial to know what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you are right but the issue is that each plot is an element of a larger domain, and hence the colorbar should represent values of the whole square (considering all elements). That is what I want to achieve, one colorbar that accounts for the whole values of the vector `zz` (now, I included a figure).

Comment: I understand. But my point is that if you want that one colorbar to represent the data in all subplots correctly, you need to use the same norm in all subplots. Once you use the same norm in all subplots, would it still matter which plot is actually the one that the colorbar represents (since they should all be equal)?

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand: What is the purpose of dividing the plot into several parts?

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks a lot for having a look at this... It will be optimal just to make a `plt.pcolor()` with a `plt.contour()`, or only one `plt.tricontourf()`, but in a finite element setting is not possible since the values `zz` correspond to the nodes of a given element (this information is stored in the matrix `IEN`). In this example, it could be 'manually' done because there is only 4 elements, but if you have 500 is not possible anymore. Thus, you need to create a `for` loop to access each element values and then use the `plt.tricontourf()` to do the plotting.

Comment: For instance, in MATLAB one can use the `fill` command, e.g. `for e = 1:nfe, fill(xx(IEN(:,e)), yy(IEN(:,e)), zz(IEN(:,e))); end,  colorbar;`. In there, the `colorbar` automatically detects the values of the whole elements plotted in the loop, where as in matplotlib, the colorbar only displays the values of the last element in the loop, and this is the issue.

Comment: Could it be that you don't actually want a `tricontourf` but a `tripcolor` plot?